# How to prevent coclass implementations from being exposed in an ATL type library

Tags: com, atl, idl

I am building an ATL type library with a type of class factory. Something sorta like this:

```
[ object, uuid(...), ... ]
interface INumber : IDispatch {
    [propget, id(0)] HRESULT Value([out, retval] LONG* pVal);
}

[ object, uuid(...), ... ]
interface INumberFactory : IDispatch {
    [id(1)] HRESULT GetNumber([in] BSTR numberName, [out, retval] INumber* pVal);
}

[ uuid(...) ]
coclass NumberFactory {
    [default] interface INumberFactory;
}
```

The user can then get an instance of a class that implements the `INumber` interface through the `NumberFactory`.

This works well, but I cannot figure out how to define and instantiate the ATL objects that are returned through the `NumberFactory.GetNumber()` method. If I define the numbers in the IDL like this:

```
[ uuid(...) ]
coclass One {
    [default] interface INumber;
}
```

the `One` coclass can be instantiated by the user. But I would like to restrict it so the only way you can get an instance of the `One` coclass is by calling `NumberFactory.GetNumber("One")`.

So my question is: How should the IDL be written so the user cannot instantiate `One`, but still be able to instantiate `One` from within then `NumberFactory` coclass and return the `INumber` interface of `One` to the user?

Additionally, is there anything special that must be done in the ATL side of things in order for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove the CoClass from the IDL
2. Remove the CoClass from the object table (remove its OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO)
3. Keep The CNumber class
4. Your code for GetNumber(...) should look something like:

> ```
> *pVal = new CComObject<CNumber>();  
> (*pVal)->AddRef();
> ```

This way there is no CoClass to create by the user and your factory is the only one who can produce them.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

This actually does what I was looking for better than what I found, lol...

Comment: You also need to remove inheritance from CComCoClass<CNumber>.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was searching for the wrong thing... I found the answer in a related question (from the sidebar) even though I was unable to find it while searching before asking the question...

The answer is two-fold:

1. Add `noncreatable` to the coclass definition in the IDL
2. Remove the `OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO` entry from the ATL header file (at the bottom if generated by the wizard)

See this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tc639ss.aspx

Comment: Actually, `noncreatable` attribute is a better way to declare PublicNotCreatable classes, because you can define source interface and allow [VB6] clients to Dim WithEvents the coclass. Otherwise clients have to use the interface decirectly.